# ¿Es mala práctica el modificar atributos en otros métodos?

Tags: java, buenas-prácticas

Me gustaría saber si se considera una mala práctica el modificar el atributo de un objeto en un método. Pongo el ejemplo:

```
public void miPrograma() {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Ana", "López"); 
    System.out.println(usuario); /*Usuario [nombre=Ana, apellido=López]*/
    cambiarNombre(usuario);
    System.out.println(usuario); /*Usuario [nombre=Manolo, apellido=López]*/
}

private void cambiarNombre(final Usuario usuario) {
    usuario.setNombre("Manolo");
}
```

Tengo entendido que no es recomendable modificar un objeto dentro de otro método, ¿Qué forma sería mejor?

¿Que el método devolviera un objeto? (en este caso es el mismo)

```
public void miPrograma() {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Ana", "López");
    System.out.println(usuario); /* Usuario [nombre=Ana, apellido=López] */
    Usuario usuarioCambiado = cambiarNombre(usuario);
    System.out.println(usuarioCambiado); /* Usuario [nombre=Manolo, apellido=López] */
}

private Usuario cambiarNombre(final Usuario usuario) {
    usuario.setNombre("Manolo");
    return usuario;
}
```

¿Que el método devolviera un nuevo objeto?

```
public void miPrograma() {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Ana", "López");
    System.out.println(usuario); /* Usuario [nombre=Ana, apellido=López] */
    Usuario usuarioCambiado = cambiarNombre(usuario);
    System.out.println(usuarioCambiado); /* Usuario [nombre=Manolo, apellido=López] */
}

private Usuario cambiarNombre(final Usuario usuario) {
    Usuario nombreCambiado = new Usuario("Manolo", usuario.getApellido());
    return nombreCambiado;
}
```

¿Seteando el valor en el mismo método?

```
public void miPrograma() {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Ana", "López");
    System.out.println(usuario); /* Usuario [nombre=Ana, apellido=López] */
    usuario.setNombre(obtenerNuevoNombre());
    System.out.println(usuario); /* Usuario [nombre=Manolo, apellido=López] */
}

private String obtenerNuevoNombre() {
    return "Manolo";
}
```

¿Alguna otra solución? ¿Cuál es la mejor opción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta de Roberto es bastante completa y puede ser lo que necesitas, pero voy a dar otra desde un punto de vista distinto:

### El código debería ser lo menos sorprendente posible

¿Qué significa *sorprendente*? Pues sencillamente que haga algo inesperado.

Cuando lees un código como:

```
double num= 3456.34;
double d= raizCubica(num);
```

Esperas que ese método calcule la raíz cúbica de 3456.24 y lo devuelva. Nada más. **No esperas** que modifique el valor de `num` porque eso sería un efecto colateral no deseado.

En cambio, si lees algo como

```
byte[] datos = new byte[1024];
File fichero= new File("/fichero.dat");
leerFichero(fichero,datos);
```

**Esperas** que el valor de `datos` sí se modifique, pasando a tener lo que hubiese en el fichero dado.

Por tanto la respuesta a tu pregunta sería: ***depende***. Hay escenarios en los que sí es lógico modificar el valor del parámetro recibido y en otros no.

Por supuesto, puedes pensar que el segundo caso podría ser reescrito como

```
byte[] datos=leerFichero("/fichero.dat");
```

y así evitar la modificación, pero hay situaciones en los que no es una buena idea:

```
List<String> ficheros = ...
byte[] datos = new byte[1024];
for (String f: ficheros) {
    long longitud = leerFichero(f,datos);
    //hacemos operaciones con datos
}
```

Este código leería datos reutilizando siempre el mismo array y luego desechando los datos, con lo que nos ahorraríamos estar reservando memoria en cada iteración. Además, puesto que cada fichero tendría una longitud distinta, necesitaríamos saber cuantos bytes se han leído, así que ya estamos devolviendo algo (no podríamos devolver el array).

El propio API de Java tiene ejemplos similares, como puede ser `Collections.sort(Collection c)`, donde el parámetro recibido se ve modificado.

Answer (score 4):

Un atributo debería estar contenido en una instancia para que sea gestionado por esta misma. El que otro objeto modificara directamente el atributo iría contra el principio de responsabilidad única, es la S de la metodología SOLID.

En tu caso concreto, el setter sería la mejor opción porque cualquier control o procesamiento puede implementarse en él (o en un método definido en la misma clase que lo llame). De esta forma conseguimos que nuestra clase sea la encargada de gestionar el valor del atributo, respetando el principio de responsabilidad única.

Si no estás familiarizado con estos conceptos, te facilito la documentación. Dado que estamos en StackOverflow en español voy a pasar enlaces en español, pero la documentación de mayor calidad está en inglés.

Para los conceptos de cohesión y acoplamiento (fundamentales para comprender SOLID), creo que se explican bien en http://latecladeescape.com/h/2015/07/acoplamiento-y-cohesion.

Para SOLID he estado buscando documentación y creo que este artículo es decente:
https://librosweb.es/libro/tdd/capitulo_7/principios_solid.html

Por supuesto, no esperes documentos tan buenos como los del autor original (https://fi.ort.edu.uy/innovaportal/file/2032/1/design_principles.pdf), pero creo que servirán.

Espero que te sea de utilidad